# Is autoloading classes from an autoloaded class function allowed in PHP?

Tags: php, drupal

I am using Drupal 7 and I am using my custom module's .info file along with the "files[] = ...." directive to allow autoloading of my classes when required. Each class only contains static public functions and everything is working nicely when these functions are called from a function of the general scope.

Working example:
If I go to /devel/php and call the function ClassTwo::getValue() everything is executed without error.

Example with error:
If I call the function ClassTwo::getValue() from within another autoloaded function ClassOne::generate() an exception is thrown that the class ClassTwo() doesn't exist. The error is solved if I specifically include the file containing the class ClassTwo.

I don't believe it has something to do with Drupal's autoloading mechanism though. Is my scenario allowed in PHP 5.3?

For better clarification I have added below example code. That's the nearest I can provide to working code.

**mymodule/mymodule.info**

```
name = "MyModule"
core = "7.x"
files[] = "includes/plugins/ClassOne.inc"
files[] = "includes/plugins/ClassTwo.inc"
```

**mymodule/mymodule.module**

```
function mymodule_page_callback() {
  return ClassOne::generate();
}
```

**mymodule/includes/plugins/ClassOne.inc**

```
Class ClassOne {
  static public function generate() {
    $value = ClassTwo::getValue();
    // Process $value
    return $value;
  }
}
```

**mymodule/includes/plugins/ClassTwo.inc**

```
Class ClassTwo {
  static public function getValue() {
    // Somehow retrieve the value. 
    return $value;
  }
}
```

UPDATE: Using Drupal's xautoload module with PSR-4 everything works incredibly fine and I have turned to this method as a solution. If anyone has an answer though, other than PSR-0/PSR-4, I would like to know it.

Comment: can you share your code please ?

Comment: Sharing the real code is not an option. But I have added an example code to the description.